# NPM cannot find nodejs

Tags: npm, terminal, command-line-interface

Every time I try to install something with npm or do npm install or anything  else with npm, I get this: `env: node: No such file or directory`. Is there anything I can do about it? (i tried reinstalling it with homebrew and node.js's website)

Comment: Are you on windows or unix?

Comment: mac's unix right? if so then unix

Comment: looks like your path is not set correctly. can you try setting that for nodejs?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `node.js` again as `node -v` or `npm -v` isn't working for you. Seems problem with node installation itself. You can download and install from https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

Comment: Any error that you got? Please run echo $PATH and paste the output.

Comment: Sure, will be glad if we can get it working. `node -v` and `npm -v` works. Right?

Comment: Hope you put a space in between. Its `npm -v` and `node -v`. What is the output?

Comment: input: npm -v output: env: node: No such file or directory input: node -v output: -bash: node: command not found

Comment: Please install nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ according to your enviroment mac or unix. And run the same commands again. Please let me know the outcome. If you are on a mac os, choose mac installer. If you are using unix operating system, lemme know, will give you the link to install.

Comment: well you should take down your answer and put install node.js again,because that was what helped me. thanks again

Comment: @anonymous, done. Please accept answer and upvote. Thanks.